# mod_rewrite Redirect Rule Variables question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a bit of an .htaccess n00b, and can't for the life of me get a handle of regular expressions.

I have the following piece of `RewriteRule` code that works just fine:

```
RewriteRule ^logo/?$ /pages/logo.html
```

Basically, it takes `/pages/logo.html` and makes it `/logo`.

Is there a way for me to generalize that code with variables, so that it works automatically without having to have an independent line for each page?

I know `$1` can work as a variable, but thats usually for queries, and I can't get it to work in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know that mod_rewrite can only handle requests to the server. So you would need to request `/logo` to have it rewritten to `/pages/logo.html`. And that’s what the rule does, it rewrites requests with the URL path `/logo` internally to `/pages/logo.html` and not vice versa.

If you now want to use portions of the matched string, you need to use groups to group them ( `(`*`expr`*`)`) that you then can reference to with `$`*`n`*. In your case the pattern `[^/]` will be suitable that describes any character other than the slash `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /pages/$1.html
```

Comment: The only thing I struggled with was getting it so that it didn't apply to the php files on my server, which weren't subject to this rewrite. 

I ended up going with 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*\.php$

Comment: You could also use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to exclude any existing regular file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)\.html$ /$1
```

The `(.*)` matches anything between `pages/` and `.html`.  Whatever it matches is used in `$1`.  So, `/pages/logo.html` becomes `/logo`, and `/pages/subdir/other_page.html` would become `/subdir/other_page`